# Finding a polynomial to satisfy a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Is there a canonical way of finding a polynomial $p$ such that
$$ p\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}? $$
If the diagonal elements of the matrix on the left were all distinct, I could use Lagrange interpolation to find a polynomial mapping $d_i \mapsto d'_i$, but in this case such a polynomial would not be well-defined. To anyone seeking to generalize this, I need the entries on the right hand side to be any of the two square roots of the corresponding entries on the left side. The diagonal entries on the left side are guaranteed to be positive.

Comment: Matrix on LHS is the identity, $I$. But $I^k=I$ for all $k\ge 0$. Therefore any polynomial of $I$ is a constant multiple of $I$.

Comment: @Fnacool aha thank you. I am trying to show that if $D$ is a diagonal matrix commuting with $A$, then for *any* square root $\sqrt{D}$ of $D$, we have $A \sqrt{D} = \sqrt{D} A$. I thought I could find a polynomial sending $D$ to $\sqrt D$, but apparently not.

Comment: Why do you think it's true ? if $D$ is $I$, then $D$ commutes with every $A$. It is not true that all square roots of $I$ commute with everything...

Comment: It's quite rare that a diagonal matrix commutes with other matrices, it puts quite a requirement on $D$ and $A$. Basically if a diagonal element is anything other than $1$ the row and column of $A$ on that index must have all off diagonal elements equals $0$. Remember that multiplying with a diagonal matrix means multiplying the rows or columns with the diagonal elements (depending on from which side the multiplication happens). To say that they commute is to say that multiplying column $j$ with $d_j$ is the same as multiplying row $j$ with $d_j$.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you point out you can do this if the diagonal elements are distinct, but you can't do it otherwise. The problem is that the diagonal elements of $P(I)$ are all $P(1)$, that is equal.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see my comment on the question.

Comment: I've noted your comment, but the problem here is that the diagonal elements of the matrix on the LHS are equal and therefore for any polynomial $P$ the diagonal elements of $P(D)$ are all equal as well, but the diagonal elements of the RHS are not all equal. That's why it's not possible.